# Stuck after waking from suspend. I see only few logs from kern.log on black screen

Tags: 20.04, suspend, wakeup

When waking up system from suspend
( triggered `systemctl suspend` ), I see only these logs on black screen:

```
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8000.162437] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x3f0900
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8000.162438] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x3f0900
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8000.162439] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x3f0900
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8002.178403] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x00170500
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8003.182389] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x00170500
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.186371] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x00170500
```

when I press F2 everything disapears, otherwise no response to keys, Ctrl+Alt+F doesn't work

kern.log:

```
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8000.162437] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x3f0900
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8000.162438] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x3f0900
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8000.162439] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x3f0900
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8002.178403] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x00170500
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8003.182389] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x00170500
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.186371] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x00170500
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.295182] OOM killer enabled.
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.295183] Restarting tasks ... done.
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.299894] PM: suspend exit
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381630] irq 77: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381634] CPU: 6 PID: 4773 Comm: TabNine Not tainted 5.4.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381635] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B450 AORUS ELITE/B450 AORUS ELITE, BIOS F51 12/18/2019
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381635] Call Trace:
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381637]  <IRQ>
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381641]  dump_stack+0x6d/0x9a
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381643]  __report_bad_irq+0x3a/0xaf
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381644]  note_interrupt.cold+0xb/0x61
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381645]  handle_irq_event_percpu+0x73/0x80
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381646]  handle_irq_event+0x3b/0x5a
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381648]  handle_fasteoi_irq+0x9c/0x150
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381649]  do_IRQ+0x55/0xf0
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381651]  common_interrupt+0xf/0xf
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381651]  </IRQ>
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381652] RIP: 0033:0xf37eec
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381653] Code: b6 f6 40 f6 c7 07 75 1b eb 24 0f 1f 40 00 0f b6 07 39 f0 74 7c 48 83 c7 01 48 83 ea 01 40 f6 c7 07 74 0b 48 85 d2 75 e6 31 c0 <c3> 0f 1f 00 31 c0 48 85 d2 74 f5 0f b6 07 39 f0 74 55 48 b8 01 01
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381654] RSP: 002b:00007fbe7cfdbd58 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffdd
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381655] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 00007fbe789c2520 RCX: 0000000000000065
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381656] RDX: 0000000000000002 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 00007fbe789c2532
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381656] RBP: 00007fbe761fbb10 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 8080808080808080
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381657] R10: fefefefefefefeff R11: 0000000000000020 R12: 00007fbe7a01ba44
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381657] R13: 000000000000000a R14: 00007fbe7cfdbdf0 R15: 00007fbe7cfdbe50
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381658] handlers:
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381664] [<0000000094f8f086>] azx_interrupt [snd_hda_codec]
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.381665] Disabling IRQ #77
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.575153] rfkill: input handler disabled
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.577916] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-300:00: attached PHY driver [Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-300:00, irq=IGNORE)
Dec  7 13:42:08 k kernel: [ 8004.687073] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
Dec  7 13:42:11 k kernel: [ 8007.735088] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Dec  7 14:49:44 k kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-56-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-025) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #62-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 23 19:20:19 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-56.62-generic 5.4.73)
Dec  7 14:49:44 k kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-56-generic root=UUID=eb14d39e-50e1-4f87-8c6b-6798ac8a4236 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

Lately I tried to make bluetooth dongle work with HSP headphones, but this happens even when dongle is deatached and it happens more frequently now. 3 times today.
I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.
It might be more frequent when suspend time are bigger. Another times when it wakes properly I see some logs before desktop shows only for a fraction of a second.
Is this problem with snd_hda_intel?